# SED command with regex, search and replace

Tags: unix, sed

I want to delete all the print statements (except print e and print (e)) using sed command from a python code file,
my sample command is:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^print\(s+\)\(["]\).*//;/^$/d' test.py
```

sample content of file is:

```
print "this is comment"
try:
    a=[1,2,3]
    print a
    print 'this is comment again'
    return a
except Exception as e:
    print e
    print (e)
```

my query is to delete all print statement except print e and print (e), my command is not working in this case, can any one suggest good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sed** solution:

```
sed '/print/{/print (*e/!d;}' test.py
```

- `/print/` - process lines with `print` statement
- `/print (*e/!d` - delete lines where `print` is not followed by `e` or `(e`

---

The output:

```
try:
    a=[1,2,3]
    return a
except Exception as e:
    print e
    print (e)
```

Comment: Thanks, but running this command return this error,
sed: 1: "/print/{/print (*e/!d}": extra characters at the end of d command

Comment: @GauravRathore, just put `;` after `d` subcommand. See my update

Comment: Yes, this is working but in stdout mode only, this command return this error,
sed -i.bak 's/print/{/print (*e/!d;}' test.py
sed: 1: "s/print/{/print (*e/!d;}": bad flag in substitute command: 'r'

Comment: @GauravRathore, I did not suggest you to use `-i.bak` option. You may try just `-i ` option

Comment: How about `print errormessage`, should this one be removed?